# Tunnel yum traffic through another server via ssh

Tags: ssh, fedora, iptables, yum, ssh-tunneling

I am running a Fedora desktop behind a corporate proxy that is blocking `yum` traffic (specifically `*.gz` and `*.bz2`).  I have access to a separate RedHat machine via ssh which can download anything it likes.

When I do `yum update` and other yum commands:  Is it possible to route that traffic to the RedHat machine to do the downloads for me?  I don't have root access on the RedHat machine but I can login and use wget to download files.  If so, how?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My solution was similar to @slm's but I used SOCKS instead because it is simpler and required no proxy installation on the server or client.

Run all commands on the computer with restricted acccess.

in `yum.conf` set the proxy as follows

```
proxy=socks5h://localhost:1080
```

from a terminal type

```
ssh -D 1080 YOUR_USER@YOUR_SERVER_WITH_FULL_WEB_ACCESS
```

press enter and type your password.

now, in a separate terminal (not the ssh one) type

```
yum update
```

Comment: I've tried using the socks5h proxy setting in yum.conf, but yum complains that its not http, https or ftp. (using Centos6)

Comment: My solution works with Fedora 20 & 21.  Cent and Fedora a similar distributions so it is a little weird that it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, the ssh command you mentioned should be run on the computer with restricted access right?  If yes, I wonder how the firewall won't block and cause the error like "ssh: connect to host YOUR_SERVER_WITH_FULL_WEB_ACCESS port 22: No route to host".  YOUR_SERVER_WITH_FULL_WEB_ACCESS is reachable from the restricted machine?

Comment: @Hei yes, "YOUR_SERVER_WITH_FULL_WEB_ACCESS" needs to be accessible from your machine.  In my case - my internet was restricted locally.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to proxy YUM's traffic over the SSH connection like so:

1. add to the `/etc/yum.conf` on the protected server:

   ```
   proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080
   ```
2. from the server with normal inbound/outbound ssh access:

   ```
   $ ssh -R 8080:ssh.server:8080 user@protected.server
   ```
3. On the server where you want to run YUM commands:

   ```
   $ yum update
   ```

#### References

- [Port Forward yum Around Draconian Firewall Restrictions](http://jwenet.net/notebook/2007/1005.html)

Comment: I just need some clarifications.  (I will refer to my Fedora desktop as `desktop` and the RedHat server with full download access as `server`).  So I guess I will need to do `proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080` on my `desktop` as this is the computer needing the yum updates and `ssh -R 8080:ssh.server:8080 user@protected.server` on my `desktop` also.  Where does the `server` configuration come into this or is there none?

Comment: You're missing the step of running an HTTP proxy that listens on port 8080 on `ssh.server`.

Comment: @Gilles do I need the proxy on my `desktop` or `server`?  If it is no the server I can't install it because I don't have root access

Comment: @jax You need to run the proxy on the machine with the Internet connection. You don't need to run it as root. Tinyproxy is easy to set up (there are many alternatives).

Comment: @Gilles, I have found elsewhere that you can create a Socks proxy whi ch apparently routes TCP traffic automatically. `ssh -D 8888 user@server` on the desktop, then you need to tell yum to use this server `proxy=socks5h://localhost:8888`.  So can you see any problem with this?  It would mean I don't need to install anything on the server machine which is ideal in my case because it is a shared machine.  I will not be able to test it out until Monday.

Comment: @jax Yes, a SOCKS proxy is another way to solve this, and SSH has a built-in one so you don't need additional software. You need either a web proxy or a SOCKS proxy, not both.